# clear used cells, doesn't work: ctrl+end detects them

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook I edit and clear very often. One time I might put `100 000` rows of data into it, another - only `200` rows. To clear the workbook I use

```
.Range("A2:AO100000").Clear
```

It deletes the visible contents of the cells, but something still remains - using keys `Ctrl+End` results in jumping to a cell far above current visible range.

I need a way to ensure all the data from previous editing gets removed and so that `Ctrl+End` proves it.

Comment: I think you need to make it clearer what you are asking. Ctrl + End implies you are talking about a sheet. Visible seems to mean ignore hidden cells, previous edit seems to imply you need to be able to do a version comparison.

Comment: @QHarr Yes I'm talking about a sheet. I don't think I have any hidden cells. All I do to cells is put data into them. Then clear those cells. Then put new data into them. But excel still thinks the used range is bigger than it really is, which is the problem - as can be checked by `Ctrl+End`ing.

Comment: @QHarr The OP is clearing from cell A2, so it is apparent that there is a header row that needs to be kept.

Comment: Could it be a table?

Comment: You have to save, close, and reopen your workbook for the clear to work.  This site explains it. https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/853903-how-to-prevent-ctrl-end-from-going-beyond-the-range-of-current-data.html

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Clear` to get rid of the data (as long as the UsedRange does not extend to the very last available row). Using `Offset(1, 0)` means that the header row is retained.

Then use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` to reset the last cell.

Comment: What's wrong with simply declaring the maximum excel range: `.Range("A1:XFD1048576").Clear`? I don't need to figure out the range, my problem is the range I try to clear doesn't get cleared entirely.

Comment: @ans - it gets cleared entirely. Try the two lines from this answer. Make sure to write `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` as well.

Comment: @Ans Yes, why specify a huge (and version specific) range when `UsedRange` covers every used cell? (and is *neat*)

Comment: @Andy G Because when specifying a specific range I'm sure Excel would try to clear exactly that range - which doesn't happen as it is. I don't see how using `UsedRange` would help.

Comment: @Andy G Ys. I run it, then try the `Ctrl+End` combination again and it points to the same cell (outside the used range) as before. I even tried to save and reopen with the same result.

Comment: @Andy G Windows 7, 64; Excel 2013.

Comment: I don't have those but expect this to work. Perhaps someone else with Windows and Excel 2013 can confirm or deny.

Comment: The approach what @AndyG has suggested would work provided you use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear` instead of `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents`. You may also try `Cells.Clear` to see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

From your example code, it appears that you want to preserve only the **header row**.  If this is the case, try:

```
Sub KeepHeaderRow()
    Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteUnusedFormats()

    Dim lLastRow As Long, lLastColumn As Long
    Dim lRealLastRow As Long, lRealLastColumn As Long

    'Delete from used range rows & columns that have no data
    'Detect end of used range including empty formatted cells
    With Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
        lLastRow = .Row
        lLastColumn = .Column
    End With

    'Find end of cells with data
    lRealLastRow = _
        Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    lRealLastColumn = _
        Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    'If used range exceeds data, delete unused rows & columns
    If lRealLastRow < lLastRow Then
        Range(Cells(lRealLastRow + 1, 1), Cells(lLastRow, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    If lRealLastColumn < lLastColumn Then
        Range(Cells(1, lRealLastColumn + 1), _
        Cells(1, lLastColumn)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'Resets LastCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel retains the used range after clearing the data, hence the reason why `ctrl + end` goes to the last range that was used in that instance of excel.  All the data has been cleared, there isn't any special cell that is being retained to prove it show the `Page Break Preview` after clearing the data and it will only show the header. To permanently get rid of the retained used range you have to save the workbook, close it, then reopen it after clearing the data, You will notice that the scroll bar gets big again because that retained range has been reset.